# How to dynamically control the visibility of controls in Liquid Template

Tags: liquid, liquid-layout

In Liquid template is it possible to set visibility of the control dynamically based on the condition. For example i want the following output but input text boxes should only get visible when user clicks on corresponding radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="questions" value="q1" />Question 1<br />
<input type="text" name="ans1" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="questions" value="q2" />Question 2<br />
<input type="text" name="ans2" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="questions" value="q3" />Question 2<br />
<input type="text" name="ans3" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is executed server-side so this is not possible. You could create logic to hide them on load, but it would never change if you wrote it in liquid.

I think this would be best accomplished with JavaScript. All Shopify themes include jQuery as well which would be your golden ticket.

Here's an example:

```
const inputs = {
  'input_1': {
    hides: ['.some_option_1']
  },
  'input_2': {
    hides: ['.some_option_2', '.some_option_3']
  },
  'input_3': {
    hides: []
  }
};

for (let input_key in inputs) {
  const input = $(`[name="${input_key}"]`);

  input.on('click', () => {
    const hides = inputs[input_key].hides.join(',');

    $('.option').show();
    $(hides).hide();
  });
}
```

With your HTML like so:

```
<button name="input_1" placeholder="1">Input 1</button>
<button name="input_2" placeholder="2">Input 2</button>
<button name="input_3" placeholder="3">Input 3</button>

<p class="option some_option_1">
  Option 1
</p>
<p class="option some_option_2">
  Option 2
</p>
<p class="option some_option_3">
  Option 3
</p>
```

Here's a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brydom/16f894Lt/